# selector with 9 patch

Tags: android

I'm try to create selector to CheckBox and replace the android:button with the selector.
In the selector i had two 9patch image , but for some reason that not work good.
the 9patch images are ok.
This the selector code:

```
<selector android:constantSize="false"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false"
       android:drawable="@drawable/bopen" />

    <item android:state_checked="true" 
     android:drawable="@drawable/bclose" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bclose" />
</selector>
```

What can i do ?

Comment: What means "doesn't work good"? Describe your problem.

Comment: This image doesn't fill parents ,it is stay in it own size

Comment: add more code here, probably example on how do you use the drawable with a CheckBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second line is missing the selector state hence you might see a problem with the selector, right?

Comment: this is my file   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector android:constantSize="false"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false"
       android:drawable="@drawable/bopen" />
   
  
    <item android:state_checked="true" 
     android:drawable="@drawable/bclose" />
   
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bclose" />
</selector>